# Run Shell script parallely

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I do create scripts and give it to production team. 
and the production team have to run all these scripts everyday.
say if there are 100 scripts they have to run nohup command for particular date 100 times.

example

```
nohup abc.sh 2018-03-01 &
nohup abc1.sh 2018-03-01 &
nohup abc2.sh 2018-03-01 & and so on till the last script.
```

now i have done the following Wrapper

```
echo "*** Start time ---> `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` ***" 
for date in `cat datefile_Prepaid_data` 
do 
date1=`echo $date|cut -d"|" -f1`
echo $date1
sh abc.sh $date1
sh abc1.sh $date1
sh abc2.sh $date1 and so on till the last script

return_code=$? 
if [ ${return_code} -eq 0 ] 
then 
echo "\n  Success... for date $date " 
else 
echo "\n   Failed... for date $date .. So exiting." 
exit 1 
fi 
done
```

but the issue is this wrapper run the scripts one by one. Do we have another approach to achieve this and also the scripts should run parallel.

I have created a separate file 'datefile_Prepaid_data' which is having the dates for which the wrapper should run.

Comment: Have you see the man page for wait? You can do something like job1 & job2& wait but you need to store the status variables seperately.

Comment: You have obviously to add an ampersand at the end of each script invocation, as you did at the command line.

Comment: Hi Pierre If i add '&' in the for loop u mean to say all the scripts will run parallel ?

Comment: Hi Wrist. No i have not see the man page. i will check it.

Comment: I want to know how to use 'wait'. and 'status variables' for each script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi If you see from the script you are not running them in parallel. To run them parallel you have to run each job in background. Like below:-

```
sh abc.sh $date1 &
sh abc1.sh $date1 &
sh abc2.sh $date1 & 
#and so on till the last script
```

But one issue here is that it will execute script from `return_code=$?` onward immediately. Hence you have to put a `wait` command so that it should wait till last job completes.

```
 wait
 #now below commend will execute only when all jobs completes.
 #also it will wait till all job completes successfully
 return_code=$?
```

Now one more problem here. Your `$?` will provide you the exit status of the last job completed. If that did not run successfully your below logic will be execute incorrectly. So you have to modify below condition based on current requirement.

```
 if [ ${return_code} -eq 0 ]
```

To know whether scripts were executed successfully or not just add below scripts in every job:-

In all abc.sh to abc99.sh

```
 echo "Job $0 completed with exit status :$? >> job_status.log
```

Now a complete answer for you:-

```
echo "*** Start time ---> `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` ***" 
for date in `cat datefile_Prepaid_data` 
do 
    date1=`echo $date|cut -d"|" -f1`
    echo $date1
    sh abc.sh $date1 &
    sh abc1.sh $date1 &
    sh abc2.sh $date1 &
        #and so on till the last script
done
```

In all abc.sh to abc99.sh

```
 echo "Job $0 completed with exit status :$? >> job_status.log
```

Comment: Hi now my colleague said that I have to add return code for every script. do we have better option ?

Comment: ok if I add 'wait' even if any script fails the rest of the jobs will run and completes. is that right ?

Comment: `for date in `cat datefile``
    `do` 
    `date1=`echo $date|cut -d"|" -f1``
    `echo $date1`
    `sh abc.sh $date1 &`
    `echo "Job $0 completed with exit status :$? >> job_status.log`
    `sh abc1.sh $date1 &`
    echo "Job $0 completed with exit status :$? >> job_status.log
    sh abc2.sh $date1 &
    echo "Job $0 completed with exit status :$? >> job_status.log
    wait
    return_code=$? 
    if [ ${return_code} -eq 0 ] 
    then 
    echo "\n  Success... for date $date " 
    else 
    echo "\n   Failed... for date $date .. So exiting." 
    exit 1 
    fi 
done

Comment: this is right ? please check the place of 

    "wait" and 
    echo "Job $0 completed with exit status :$? >> job_status.log

Comment: That is right. But if you put `echo "Job $0 completed with exit status :$? >> job_status.log` line at the end of all the 100 script you don't even need rest of the code from `wait` itself. Please keep in mind if in you scripts file there is `exit` command is there at the end of the file then add above line of code just before `exit`. `exit` must be the last line.

Comment: ok thanks i wil remove if condition. and 1 more thing this job_status single file will have all the errors or it will over write it ?

Comment: It will append. I am using `>>` this will append all the log into this file. No overwrite at all.

Comment: if you dont mind please share the complete answer with changes in my code. so that it will help others as well. and thanks for ur time

Comment: I have modified my answer. Also provide me a sample abc.sh file scripts